# Always getting error "OAuth2: No authorization context present" while using OAuth2 library in swift

Tags: ios, swift, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using [OAuth2](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2) for integrating **Outlook Calendar API**s with my iOS app.I was following with this tutorial: [Adding Calendar and Contacts APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/ios-tutorial#adding-calendar-and-contacts-apis).

After the login UI, the presenting controller dismisses. Following that, while trying to implement any APIs (Calendar, Mail, etc), it shows this error:

**OAuth2: No authorization context present**

Anyone please help! I have been sitting for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this pull request: https://github.com/jasonjoh/swift-tutorial/pull/8

There was a change (either in XCode or p2.oauth2) since that tutorial was written. You need to use a different signature for your app delegate.

Comment: Can we use this library https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS instead of https://github.com/p2/OAuth2 for OAuth2 authentication in Outlook Calendar APIs?

Comment: I don't have any experience with it, but I don't see why not :)